# Python: Convert JSON bytes object to pandas on Linux

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a bytes object that contains JSON data:

```
downloaded_bytes   # type(bytes)
```

On Windows, I can run the following and process the file without problem, in any of these two ways:

```
# works
testresult_json = downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8-sig')
testresultdb = pd.read_json(testresult_json, lines=True)

# also works
pd.read_json(BytesIO(downloaded_bytes), lines=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Using this package, I can recreate the error on Linux like so:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = literal_eval(downloaded_bytes.decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

Yielding the value error:

```
ValueError: Protocol not known: {"ntp":"synced",....
```

What other ways might I be able to decode this bytes object and transform it into a pandas dataframe such that Linux will find it tolerable?

Comment: Why are you mentioning `literal_eval` in the first place? Does `pd.read_json(BytesIO(downloaded_bytes)` throw? Where do `downloaded_bytes` come from? Is the content *the same*? Or are the files stored differently on each machine?

Comment: Why you use different method on Linux and Windows?

Comment: The method is the same for windows and Linux. The literal eval is just, as described, illustrative of the error